# How to prove that the function is injective (one to one)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions

Question: Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are functions such that $gof[x]\subseteq X$ and $X\subseteq A$.

We have to show that $f$ is injective function.

First, let $x_1,x_2\in A$, assume that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ how to show that $x_1=x_2$.

$gof[X]= \left \{ x\in A |\exists y\in f[x], g(y)=x\right \}$ note $f[X]$ is image of X over $f$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)\;\implies$$
$$gof(x_1)=gof(x_2) \; $$

Comment: Thanks, can I ask you more question if $g$ is surjective ( on to) that implies $f$ is one to one.

Comment: Not in general. But if $|A| = |B| = n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $g$ is surjective if and only if $g$ is injective.